# Get Mulesoft artifact from Anypoint Exchange and deploy it to the Coudhub 1.0

Tags: mulesoft, cloudhub, anypoint-platform, anypoint-exchange

How to get Mulesoft artifact (latest version) from Anypoint Exchange and deploy to the Coudhub using an API?

I am curruntly developing a CICD pipeline for the Muleapp deployments. Curruntly the build pipeline has been developed and the build artifact is saving in the anypoint exchange. So now i'm tring to implement release pipeline. Basically now i want to get the latest version of artifact from the exchange and deploy the application.

Comment: Please add a question to the body of the question, what you already tried and the result. Is the question for CloudHub 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: Hi @aled, this is a question for Cloudhub 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

The option to deploy the artifact from Anypoint Exchange is only available in Cloudhub 2.0. In Cloudhub 1.0, we directly upload the jar file into Runtime Manager during deployment(Maven/Anypoint CLI). So, It's a one step process in Cloudhub 1.0 as opposed to two steps for Cloudhub 2.0(Upload to Exchange + Deploy to runtime manager)

Because of this restriction, consider publishing your build artifacts to other repositories(For e.g. Azure artifacts) instead of Anypoint Exchange. And then creating a separate release selecting the latest version from published artifacts.

**References:**

For Cloudhub 2.0, refer to prerequisites("The application is already published in Exchange" -
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/deploy-to-cloudhub-2

For Cloudhub 1.0, there is no such prerequisites  -
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/deploy-to-cloudhub